# IlegalArgumentException ao reabrir jInternalFrame várias vezes

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

Estou com uma aplicação que está validando quando a janela `JInternalFrame` está aberta ou fechada, mas se a janela for aberta e fechada algumas vezes seguidas, o console apresenta um erro e não abre novamente o `JInternalFrame`.

[image: Demonstração do Erro]

Janela com JDesktopPane:

```
package janelas;

public class desktop extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private frameInterno register;

    public desktop() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        painelDesktop = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane();
        btnAbrirFrame = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout painelDesktopLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(painelDesktop);
        painelDesktop.setLayout(painelDesktopLayout);
        painelDesktopLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            painelDesktopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        painelDesktopLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            painelDesktopLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 260, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        btnAbrirFrame.setText("Abrir Frame");
        btnAbrirFrame.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnAbrirFrameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(painelDesktop)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(301, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnAbrirFrame)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(painelDesktop, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(btnAbrirFrame)
                .addGap(0, 11, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }

    private void btnAbrirFrameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        if (register == null) {
            register = new frameInterno();
        }

        if (!register.isVisible()) {
            painelDesktop.add(register);
            register.setVisible(true);
        }
        register.toFront();
    }                                             

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new desktop().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JButton btnAbrirFrame;
    private javax.swing.JDesktopPane painelDesktop;

}
```

Janela JInternalFrame:

```
package janelas;

public class frameInterno extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    public frameInterno() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        btnSair = new javax.swing.JButton();

        btnSair.setText("Sair");
        btnSair.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnSairActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnSair)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnSair)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }

    private void btnSairActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        this.dispose();
    }

    private javax.swing.JButton btnSair;
}
```

Erro (exception):

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position  at
> java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1100)     at
> javax.swing.JLayeredPane.addImpl(JLayeredPane.java:231)     at
> javax.swing.JDesktopPane.addImpl(JDesktopPane.java:484)     at
> java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:417)  at 
> janelas.desktop.btnAbrirFrameActionPerformed(desktop.java:63)   at
> janelas.desktop.access$000(desktop.java:3)  at 
> janelas.desktop$1.actionPerformed(desktop.java:31)  at
> javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)    at
> javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)    at
> javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)     at
> javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)  at
> javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)  at
> java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)   at
> javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)  at
> java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)    at
> java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)    at
> java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)   at
> java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)   at
> java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)   at
> java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)  at
> java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)   at
> java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)   at
> java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)   at
> java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)     at
> java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)   at
> java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)  at
> java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)  at
> java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)  at 
> java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)  at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
> java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)     at
> java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)     at
> java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)  at
> java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)  at 
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
> java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)     at
> java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)  at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)   at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)  at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)   at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)   at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)    at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> ```

Comment: +1 pelo vídeo explicativo. Consegue copiar e colar o erro (exception) na sua pergunta também? Não dá para ver bem o motivo do erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em resumo, o erro ocorre porque está sendo adicionado um componente que o `JDesktopPane` já possui adicionado. Mas no caso do seu código, está havendo um `dispose()` no frame interno, e este método do frame interno faz com que ele se torne *"invisível, não selecionável e fechado"*<sup>[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#dispose--)</sup>, o que deveria removê-lo do `JDesktopPane`.

Não consegui debugar o código por completo, mas posso deduzir que isso ocorre devido ao frame interno não deixar de existir, pois como já explicado, o *dispose* não destrói a instância.

---

**Errata sobre a explicação do erro**

> O que causa o erro realmente é o fato do `dispose()` não destruir a referencia do frame interno, só o torna não-exibível, e o gerenciador de componentes do `JDesktopPane`, apesar de removê-lo uma primeira vez, não repete esta ação na segunda, o que gera a exceção pois o componente já está incluso, e você tenta inclui-lo novamente.

---

Para evitar esse tipo de problema e conforme já explicado o funcionamento do *dispose()* para com frames internos, é melhor alterar a visibilidade ao invés de dar *dispose*, pois a instancia vai ficar disponível de qualquer jeito, então, apenas altere o método de fechamento do frame interno para:

```
private void btnSairActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    this.setVisible(false);
}
```

E com essa alteração, não é necessário adicionar mais de uma vez o componente no *desktoppane*, então, mova a adição para dentro do if:

```
private void btnAbrirFrameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if (register == null) {
        register = new frameInterno();
        painelDesktop.add(register);    
    }

    if (!register.isVisible()) {
        register.setVisible(true);
    }
    register.toFront();
}
```

Com isso, o erro nao ocorre mais:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

---

<sup>1 - fonte: [documentação da classe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#dispose--)</sup>